# One device for multiple IOS Developer Program Accounts

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-developer-program

If i register device(in my Developer Account), that belongs to my company and registered in their iOS Developer Account, do they have possibility to know about that (and cut my head:)?

Comment: No, there isn't an obvious way. But do not do something that you shouldn't do, because in the end, they will find out.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way for them to find out what third-party programs or provisioning profiles a device is registered with.

Comment: If it's managed through the enterprise management, they might well have access to provisioning profiles installed.

Answer (score 1):

If they go to Settings > General > Profiles on the device, they will see your developer account profile in there if you don't delete it every time.

But other than that, they can't discover this information from their developer account.